# Slopes on roads in map tiles. How to obtain them?

Tags: here-api

I would like to be able to show the slope of the streets using map tiles. However, I can't see from the documentation that this information is available.

Can anyone help ? Either to confirm that it is not possible or to lead me in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For getting this info you need to use Platform Data Extension
https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/introduction.html